# Mysql with springboot application deployed on Docker windows desktop error

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, compiler-errors, dockerfile

I am a new docker application user, I have been trying to deploy my application using docker for windows and I have been successful in creating MYSQL and application images/Container and confirmed that my container is up an running

**

```
    PS C:\Users\LIFE 3\eclipse-workspace\Arkk> docker ps -a
    CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                            PORTS                    NAMES
1776f9cc175c        arkk-app            "java -jar arkk-app.…"   21 hours ago        Up 24 seconds                     0.0.0.0:8085->8085/tcp   arkk-app-container
01d1191cacfb        mysql:8             "docker-entrypoint.s…"   22 hours ago        Up About an hour                  3
```

**I also created a network arknet which my app/mysql container runs on**

```
PS C:\Users\LIFE 3\eclipse-workspace\Arkk> docker network ls                                                                                                                                                                                                                   NETWORK ID          NAME                     DRIVER              SCOPE
42dffaf576e3        Default Switch           ics                 local
70bd03f5eff8        Primary Virtual Switch   transparent         local
abb7f62bb700        arknet                   nat                 local
112759e62dbc        nat                      nat                 local
bdc9465104cc        none                     null                local

PS C:\Users\LIFE 3\eclipse-workspace\Arkk> docker container run --network arknet --name arkk-app-container -p 8085:8085  -d arkk-app 

PS C:\Users\LIFE 3\eclipse-workspace\Arkk> docker container run --name arkinventory --network arknet -e MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=True -e MYSQL_DATABASE=arkkk -e MYSQL_USER=root -e MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=True -d mysql:8
```

**However, after above steps I tried to run a log on my application image container so as to verify if my code is working but I got the following error..**

PS C:\Users\LIFE 3\eclipse-workspace\Arkk> docker logs  arkk-app-container

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
```

**Whenever I change my container ID which is (arkd) in my application properties to LOCALHOST. then the application seems to run...

Please note: I am using my local database. the name of my local database is arkkk and my local database name created in a docker container is arkinventory**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://arkinventory:3306/arkkk?serverTimezone=UTC

spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
#spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
#spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
# hibernate configurations
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialet = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect


# thumeleaf configurations
spring.thymeleaf.mode= LEGACYHTML5
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false

#Spring Security login queries
security.basic.enabled=false
spring.queries.users-query=select email, password, '1' as enabled from auth_user where email=? and status='VERIFIED'
spring.queries.roles-query=select u.email, r.role_name from auth_user u inner join auth_user_role ur on(u.auth_user_id=ur.auth_user_id) inner join auth_role r on(ur.auth_role_id=r.auth_role_id) where u.email=?

server.port=8085
```

**Below code is my dockfile which I have created in my spring-boot application**

```
 FROM openjdk:8
    ADD target/arkk-app.jar arkk-app.jar
    EXPOSE 8085
    ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","arkk-app.jar"]
```

Please help to resolve this.Thank you

Comment: Are your `spring-application` container and `mysql-db` container in the same `docker-network`? Please add the commands used to create `mysql` and you application containers as well as the full stack trace of the application error.

Comment: Did you check your database working or not using Workbench or something?

Comment: Also, whatever the containers you posted up there, are not running. Their statuses are `Exited`.